# Rename a MySQL column containing ` in the column name

Tags: mysql, alter, backticks

So, the other guy at work created a table with a column called:

```
    Max(`abs_spg_20090430`.`ID`)
```

this is giving me an error now that I am trying to run a dump of the database on a different server.

I am trying to rename it, but

```
    ALTER TABLE abs_spgID_20090504 CHANGE Max(`abs_spg_20090430`.`ID`) id bigint default null;
```

as well as

```
    ALTER TABLE abs_spgID_20090504 CHANGE `Max(`abs_spg_20090430`.`ID`)` id bigint default null;
```

give me an error. Does any of you friendly people have a hint? Many thanks!

Comment: The column name has parenthesis `( )` **and** backquotes? wow!

Comment: Please *always* quote the exact error message that you are getting.

Comment: `Max(`abs_spg_20090430`.`ID`)` is not a column, it's a function call

Comment: I think, you're watching a **view**, not a table.

Comment: no, this other guy really did choose that name for the column.

Answer (score 3):

you need to quote your quotes and the column too, e.g:

```
ALTER TABLE abs_spgID_20090504  CHANGE `Max(``abs_spg_20090430``.``ID``)` id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: This almost work, but the server complained about the period now. I did create another table with the same fields, but more normal names, and then did a 
insert into tmp select * from abs_spgID_20090504;
and then just delete the first table, and rename the second one. Thanks a lot anyways! I appreciate your input

Comment: strange, when I created the column exactly as stated the command worked fine for me